# Why $dQ$ and $dL$ are not exact differentials, while instead $dU$ is exact?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, differentiation, first-law-of-thermodynamics

Why $dQ$ and $dL$ are not exact differentials, while instead $dU$ is exact? Is there a way to see it analytically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: tdm system]

If you consider the generic system in the figure above, the balance of energy is given by:
$$\int_{t_{0}}^t{\dot{Q(s)} ds}-\int_{t_{0}}^t{\dot{L(s)} ds}+U(t_{0})=U(t)$$
$U(t)$ represents the energy which is stored by the system.

(It is the first tdm principle:
$Q-L=\Delta U$)
Also you have:
$$[\int{\dot{Q(s)}-\dot{L(s)} ds}](t)-[\int{\dot{Q(s)}-\dot{L(s)} ds}](t_{0})+U(t_{0})=U(t)$$
$$[\int{\dot{Q(t)}-\dot{L(t)} dt}]+cost=U(t)$$
Deriving you obtain:
$$\dot{Q(t)}-\dot{L(t)}=\dot{U(t)}$$
and also:
$$\delta Q-\delta L=dU$$
Now you integer this expression:
$$\int_{t_0}^{t}{\delta Q}-\int_{t_0}^{t}{\delta L}=\int_{t_0}^{t}{dU}$$
And you compare it with the first expression:
$$\int_{t_{0}}^t{\delta Q}-\int_{t_{0}}^t{\delta L}+U(t_{0})=U(t)$$
You see that:
$$\int_{t_0}^{t}{dU}=U(t)-U(t_{0})$$
Which is the definition of exact differential.
While:
$$\int_{t_0}^{t}{\delta Q}\neq Q(t)-Q(t_{0}) $$
$$\int_{t_0}^{t}{\delta L}\neq L(t)-L(t_{0}) $$

Comment: Great to see the reputable Landau on this website.

Comment: Glad to meet my fans. @ArturodonJuan

Answer (score 0):

U is a physical property of the material that depends only on its present thermodynamic state.  Q and L are quantities that not only depend on the present state, but also the path by which it arrived at its present state.